# Inverting the case of characters within a defined region [Scala]

Tags: scala, junit

I'm trying to write a function that inverts the case of any alphabetic chars within a defined region (from the cursor position to the marker position) however I'm struggling.

I have a feeling that something very similar to this would work, but I can't get my head around it.

```
def invertCase() {
this.getString.map(c => if(c.isLower) c.toUpper else c.toLower)
}
```

I need to invert the case of the alphabetic characters within a defined region, which (as far as I'm aware) I am doing by calling this.getString (getString gets the buffer and converts it to a string).

So by doing this.getString I believe I am selecting the region which needs to have its alphabetic characters inverted, yet the code following it doesn't do what I want it to.

Any pointers?

Thank you!

**EDIT: the buffer is of type StringBuilder if that changes anything**

xd

Answer (score 0):

You can use `splitAt` and `map` to invert part of the string as follows:

```
def invertBetween(start: Int, end: Int, str: String) = { 
  val (a, bc) = str.splitAt(start)
  val (b, c) = bc.splitAt(end - start)
  a + b.map(c => if (c.isUpper) c.toLower else c.toUpper) + c 
}
```

Example:

```
invertBetween(3, 10, "Hello, World, Foo, BAR, baz")
      res10: String = HelLO, wORld, Foo, BAR, baz
                         ^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `collect` with `zipWithIndex`

```
scala> val start = 4
start: Int = 4

scala> val end = 9
end: Int = 9

scala> val result = ("Your own String value.").zipWithIndex.collect {
  case e if(e._2 >= start && e._2 <= end) => if (e._1.isLower) e._1.toUpper else e._1.toLower
  case e => e._1
}.mkString("")
result: String = Your OWN string value.
```